# PHP session not staying alive. headers already sent

Tags: php, session

I'm having trouble keeping my session alive, it times out after 3 hours (our desired custom timeframe) regardless of user activity. It used to keep the session alive for the next 3 hours every time somebody changes pages on the site. Now i get the "Headers already sent" error in the error log every time somebody changes pages. The session is created correctly but it cant be updated without the headers already sent error occurring.

My session_start function is added to wordpress init action, as suggested in the wordpress docs. I've simplified the code to the bare minimum and still no success.

```
function checkmateStartSession()
{
    if(!session_id())
    {
        session_name('SESCHECKMATEID');
        session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 300]); // 5 minutes for testing purposes
    }
}
add_action('init', 'checkmateStartSession', 1);
```

I've tried output buffering with ob_start() before the session_name() line and ob_end_flush() after session_start() to no avail.

I've disabled the plugins folder, problem persisted.

Changing the theme deactivates the functions.php file in which my session code lives, so the code goes back to wordpress default session code. Am I missing something in a newer update? This code used to work.

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP sessions won't work with a lot of caching plugins out there, or if you have a caching layer such as Varnish or cloudfront. Some hosts just outright refuse to work with them, e.g. WP Engine. Also keep in mind that this isn't a way to avoid cookies, PHP will set a cookie so that it knows the session ID. Consider using cookies instead

Comment: As i mentioned in the post, I have disabled all plugins and we do not use a cache plugin to begin with. The implementation does use cookies. Rather than the PHPSESSID cookie, this creates a cookie named SESCHECKMATEID with a 5 minute expiration. My problem is that i would like the expiration to be extended with every successive page visit within the current expiration window. Instead it just ends 5 minutes after login.

Comment: hmmm tbh I'm not sure that WordPress knowledge will be able to help you, this seems like a generic PHP question better suited to stackoverflow. WordPress itself doesn't use PHP sessions. Your headers already sent note suggests you're trying to start and end a PHP session after output has already been sent to the browser, which is not possible because of the way HTTP works. Either that or something somewhere is outputting stuff before or on the `init` hook, which will cause that warning on session calls as well as a lot of other WP things like AJAX etc. Normally the error says where it happened

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Tom. I posted it here mainly because this code is added to the wordpress init hook, so i thought wordpress knowledge would be preferable, since sessions are such basic creatures. The session uses the cookie implementation same as wordpress would do with PHPSESSID, I just rename it and change the lifetime.